# Return records that only have a certain status from a select query that includes multiple joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query:

```
SELECT OV.[inv_disp] AS Inv_Disp
      ,OV.[solineid] AS SO_Line_ID
      ,SO.[order_num] AS Order_Num
      ,SOL.[SOID] AS SO_ID
      ,SOL.[OrderDate] AS Order_Date
FROM [Order_View] OV
INNER JOIN [dbo].[SOline] SOL on OV.solineid = SOL.lineid
INNER JOIN [dbo].[SO] SO on SOL.SOQTID = SO.SOQTID
```

That returns records such as these:

```
Inv_Disp    SO_Line_ID  Order_Num   SO_ID   Order_Date
I            3417119    2003766     2254221 2021-03-31 00:00:00.000
I            3422822    2007943     2258398 2021-04-05 00:00:00.000
I            3422823    2007943     2258398 2021-04-05 00:00:00.000
P            3423523    2008468     2258923 2021-04-06 00:00:00.000
I            3423524    2008468     2258923 2021-04-06 00:00:00.000
I            3423522    2008322     2258211 2021-04-04 00:00:00.000
CH           3423521    2008321     2258210 2021-04-03 00:00:00.000
```

I want to be able to only return records that only have 'I' values under Inv_Disp where the Order_Num may or may not be the same. But where if an Order_Num Inv_Disp contains an 'I' AND some other value such as 'CH' or 'P' that it would not return the records for that Order_Num at all.

So the final output should only return:

```
Inv_Disp    SO_Line_ID  Order_Num   SO_ID   Order_Date
I            3417119    2003766     2254221 2021-03-31 00:00:00.000

I            3422822    2007943     2258398 2021-04-05 00:00:00.000
I            3422823    2007943     2258398 2021-04-05 00:00:00.000

I            3423522    2008322     2258211 2021-04-04 00:00:00.000
```

It should not return

```
Inv_Disp    SO_Line_ID  Order_Num   SO_ID   Order_Date
P            3423523    2008468     2258923 2021-04-06 00:00:00.000
I            3423524    2008468     2258923 2021-04-06 00:00:00.000

CH           3423521    2008321     2258210 2021-04-03 00:00:00.000
```

Because I have the two INNER JOINS do I need to SELECT INTO a temp table and then query that temp table or can I just directly query the query somehow? I am probably over-complicating this...

Comment: Is there a value that is unique in each row, e.g. `SO_Line_ID`?

Comment: Hi @HABO, SO_LINE_ID is unique as a matter of fact.

Comment: @DaleK I apologize for taking so long to respond I took leave from work the next day and had forgotten that I had posted the question the evening before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

…

```
select *
from
(
SELECT OV.[inv_disp] AS Inv_Disp
      ,OV.[solineid] AS SO_Line_ID
      ,SO.[order_num] AS Order_Num
      ,SOL.[SOID] AS SO_ID
      ,SOL.[OrderDate] AS Order_Date,
      max(case when OV.[inv_disp] = 'I' then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by SO.[order_num]) as OrderHasNonI, --..this
      min(case when OV.[inv_disp] = 'I' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by SO.[order_num]) as OrderHasIOnly --..or that
FROM [Order_View] OV
INNER JOIN [dbo].[SOline] SOL on OV.solineid = SOL.lineid
INNER JOIN [dbo].[SO] SO on SOL.SOQTID = SO.SOQTID
) as t
where OrderHasNonI = 0 -- ... choose one condition of the two (both are equivalent) and the corresponding column(this/that)
or OrderHasIOnly = 1
```

Comment: lptr this solved my problem and identified all order records that I was looking for which is why I marked your answer as the prevailing one. I really appreciate the help. I had gone on vacation the next day which is why it took me so long to respond. Thank you again. You have taught me something new as well!

Comment: … @ozfive..   that’s very kind of you!

Answer (score 2):

Use a CTE which you can then use to check whether a row exists for the order with a "non-I" value. Could be this row or another row.

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT
        OV.[inv_disp] AS Inv_Disp
        , OV.[solineid] AS SO_Line_ID
        , SO.[order_num] AS Order_Num
        , SOL.[SOID] AS SO_ID
        , SOL.[OrderDate] AS Order_Date
    FROM [Order_View] OV
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[SOline] SOL ON OV.solineid = SOL.lineid
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[SO] SO ON SOL.SOQTID = SO.SOQTID
)
SELECT *
FROM cte c1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte c2 WHERE c2.Order_num = c1.Order_Num and Inv_Disp != 'I');
```

Comment: Hi Dale I really appreciate your answer because it addresses my question about whether I should use a temp table or not and actually gives me something new (CTE) that I hadn't known about before. Unfortunately your answer failed to identify orders where there where > 1 one 'I' records and 0 non-I records for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
;With CTE as
(
SELECT OV.[inv_disp] AS Inv_Disp
      ,OV.[solineid] AS SO_Line_ID
      ,SO.[order_num] AS Order_Num
      ,SOL.[SOID] AS SO_ID
      ,SOL.[OrderDate] AS Order_Date
  FROM [Order_View] OV
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[SOline] SOL on OV.solineid = SOL.lineid
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[SO] SO on SOL.SOQTID = SO.SOQTID
),
CTE1 as
(
select * from CTE C where Inv_Disp in('P','CH')

)
select * from CTE C
where not exists (select 1 from CTE1 C1 
where c.Order_Num=c1.Order_Num)
```

Well it depend upon query plan,I use extra CTE to  avoid(!=)  `Inv_Disp != 'I'`.

So may be you should put result of `CTE` in `temp` table.

Comment: Could you explain why you would avoid '!=' in the query? I am interested in what it has to do with a query plan? I am also not familiar with query plans as I am not that far advanced in MS SQL. Hence the original question.